# Align drawable image inside a text view to center

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview which holds an image and some text.

programmatically i have added the drawable image to the left side of text view

```
txtIDFav.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.fav_enabled, 0, 0, 0);
```

i have aligned the text view to center using

```
txtIDFav.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Now the text in the textview is aligned to center. but the image is on the left side.

eg: [image]**_____________________** mytext

used the _ to give space as its not allowed.

I want to align the image to center along with the text.

eg: **_____________________**[image]mytext

Please advice.

Thanks and appreciate.

Comment: Can you not set the drawable as the background of the `TextView`?

Comment: Try using this : android:drawablePadding="10dip" in your XML.Hope it works.

Comment: @AndiM I have already used padding in my xml file and it does not work. the image is aligned to left and text in center.

Answer (score 9):

I was also facing the same issue, But I don't want to use Button and TextView separately and also I don't want to make it using java code. So I found this. I know I am giving solution late. But it helps you

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/next_btn_bg_rounded_corners">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btn_restore_purchases"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@null"
                android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/restore"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:drawableStart="@mipmap/restore"
                android:text="@string/restore_purchases"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

[image: icon with text in center]

Answer (score 5):

You can try this, it should work:

```
    Spannable span = new SpannableString("  " + txtIDFav.getText());  // or set your text manually

    Drawable drawable;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_enabled, getContext().getTheme());
    }
    else {
        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_enabled);
    }

    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable);
    span.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    txtIDFav.setText(span);
```

Comment: Please, write a comment when you downvote the answer, so that I can know what is problem and try to fix it.

Comment: @SaQada Can you please tell me, how can we provide drawablePadding using this?

Answer (score 0):

Embed the drawable in your text by using a SpannableString.

```
        SpannableStringBuilder textspan = new SpannableStringBuilder("  " + yourText);
        Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_enabled);
        // jump drawable to the text view's state (if it is a state drawable)
        icon.setState(textView.getBackground().getState());  // match the background state
        textspan.setSpan(new ImageSpan(icon, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM), 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(textspan);
```

Comment: I am getting error here     icon.setState(txtIDFav.getBackground().getState());

Comment: ok, your txtview doesn't have a background drawable set.. you can ignore that line then.

Comment: now it does not crash but it does not show the image too. it shows only the text.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is happened because the width of textView is set to `match_parent` or `fill_parent`. Try setting textView width to `wrap_content` and center the whole textView not only text.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="28sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textViewTest=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTest);
        textViewTest.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stwLf.png)

Comment: This is not a proper answer because when you make your textview width to match-parent(0dp) then it will not work.

Comment: @Subho that's true. But there is no info in the question that textView width  must to be set to match_parent, so why not solve problem that way?

Comment: setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds method has four property according to your answer you can set drawable at left or right. SO where is it about center it is easily understandable that textview is match parent. Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/39958875/3278589

Answer (score -1):

You have to write code like this:-

```
txtIDFav.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Comment: Down vote reason helps me to correct my answer if I am wrong.

Answer (score -2):

it is not possible to set image in background of text view instead of this you can set your drawable on textview like this

**android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"**

"or"

**android:drawableleft="@drawable/ic_launcher"**

"or"

**android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"**

only for your problem's solution you can use texview inside the framelayout in this way

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</FrameLayout>
```