# Center ImageView and TextView Side by side

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to center all contents layout to center but this is problem I am having:

[image]

As you can see, I want to center image and text in their parent but want to have image to left of text.

Here is layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_light_green" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toastImage"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/exclamation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toastText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/app_darker_green"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/39958875/3278589

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a horizontal Linearlayout and add your TextView and ImageView inside it and then add the Linearlayout in Relativelayout and make it center.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toastImage"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/exclamation"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toastText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/app_darker_green"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp"/>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Without imageview tale a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/39958875/3278589

Answer (score 1):

Try using framelayout.
In framelayout, add imageview and textview, assign gravity to be left for imageview and gravity to be center for textview. And atlast give some left margin to imageview in order to align it with textview.

Alternate soln with relativelayout is,
in your imageview tag use property
 align_toLeftOf=“@+id/R.id.Textview1"

And remove center in parent from imageview.
Your problem will be solved.

Please ignore the syntax I have typed this answer from phone. :)

Answer (score 0):

i am also bringing minel..just for simplicity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/app_light_green" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toastText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/exclamation"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:textColor="@color/app_darker_green"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

with mine you do not have to worry about imageview, you just position your textview in the center that's all..

Comment: You are putting the padding and using drawableLeft that is not the solution